# Dynamic data in Google Earth mobile

Tags: google-api, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Is there any way to build a mobile Google Earth-based application that can show dynamic (periodically changing) data?

Here is what I have found

- There is no GE plugin for mobile (iOS, Andriod) so the Javascript API is out
- There is no supported native API
- The NetworkLink RefreshInterval KML does not work on mobile versions (I can't get any part of the NetworkLink KML element to work)

Answer (score 1):

[NetworkLinkControl Updates](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#update) DO work with the Google Earth Application for mobile devices.

1. Load a KML from the internet - inside this KML, have a `NetworkLink` such as:

   ```
   <NetworkLink>
       <name>Update</name>
       <Link>
           <href>URL of Updating KML</href>
           <refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
           <refreshInterval>20</refreshInterval>
       </Link>
   </NetworkLink>
   ```

So, every 20 seconds GE tries to load the 'URL of Updating KML'

1. Create the 'Updating KML' - which will have `<Update>` commands such as:

   ```
     <NetworkLinkControl>
          <Update>
               <targetHref>URL of initial KML (one to make changes to)</targetHref>
                    <Change>
                         <Placemark targetId="placemarkID">
                              <visibility>0</visibility>
                         </Placemark>
                    </Change>
          </Update>
     </NetworkLinkControl>
   ```

That example would look for a Placemark with the id of 'placemarkID' and change its visibility to 0 (invisible)

My example is using the [Change](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#change) feature of updating, there are also `Create` and `Delete`

Here is a [Google Example](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/updates) of using `Updates`